# Slick slider for up-sells products in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, slick.js

I need to make a carousel for up-sells products. For this, I use [slick-slider](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

Script connection:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.9.0/slick/slick.css"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.9.0/slick/slick-theme.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.9.0/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Script initialization:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     

    $('.multiple-items').slick({
        infinite: true,
        autoplay: true,
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 4
    });
});
```

The code from the file up-sells.php:

```
if ( $upsells ) : ?>

<section class="up-sells upsells products">

    <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'You may also like&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

        <?php foreach ( $upsells as $upsell ) : ?>

            <?php
                $post_object = get_post( $upsell->get_id() );

                setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object );

                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product-carousel' );

        <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

</section>

<?php endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

---

**UPDATE:** File content-product-carousel.php:

```
<div class="carousel"><div class="multiple-items">
    <div <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>
        <?php
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' );
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
            do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
        ?>
   </div>  
</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.slick-slider {width: 100%; float: left;}
.slick-slide {cursor: pointer;}
.multiple-items .slick-slide {margin: 0 15px;}
.carousel {padding: 0 3%; float: left; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;}
```

Unfortunately, I can’t make a product carousel. Products are shown in one column and the slider script does not want to work. I need your help. How to make carousel products up-sells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You placed your code in the wrong place, slack is initialized multiple times. You should place "carousel" and "multiple-items" divs outside the loop, otherwise it's initialized for every element.. Correct code is as follow:

content-product.php - default, there is no need for any customization

up-sells.php

```
    <section class="up-sells upsells products">
    <?php
    $heading = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_upsells_products_heading', __( 'You may also like&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ) );

    if ( $heading ) :
        ?>
        <h2><?php echo esc_html( $heading ); ?></h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>
    <div class="carousel">
        <div class="multiple-items">
        <?php foreach ( $upsells as $upsell ) : ?>

            <?php
            $post_object = get_post( $upsell->get_id() );

            setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited, Squiz.PHP.DisallowMultipleAssignments.Found

            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
            ?>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>


</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Everything works great.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a duplicate of your content-product.php and rename it whatever you want e.g. content-product-carousel.php in that file you will create your slick slider. but you need to change the following line in your up-sells.php

```
wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
```

to

```
wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product-carousel' );
```

this is to reference the duplicated file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try to do that.

Comment: Just let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Unfortunately, the script does not want to work. The site on localhost, so I can not show it. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work for me as the all products were contained in 1 slide.

Changing the placement of the code worked:

```
    <section class="up-sells upsells products">
    <?php
    $heading = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_upsells_products_heading', __( 'You may also like&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ) );

    if ( $heading ) :
        ?>
        <h2><?php echo esc_html( $heading ); ?></h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>
    <div class="responsive-upsells">
        <?php foreach ( $upsells as $upsell ) : ?>
        <div class="card">
            <?php
            $post_object = get_post( $upsell->get_id() );

            setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited, Squiz.PHP.DisallowMultipleAssignments.Found

            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product-carousel' );
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </div>
    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>
    
    
</section>
```